# In what short story does a dying man pay to be frozen for a future cure, and awakes to find he is in a warehouse for spare body parts?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short story from 50+ years ago, about a man with an incurable disease who has himself frozen until a future cure is found, wakes to feel someone grabbing his foot, saying something like ”Here’s a good leg. We can use this.”

Thought it was by Ronald Dahl, but only thing similar I’ve found is Arthur Clarke’s “Awakening”.

Comment: Larry Niven wrote a set of stories about black market organ harvesting but I don’t recall if this is in any of them.

Comment: Larry Niven wrote a somewhat similar novel A World Out of Time in which the frozen person awoke to find his memories had been copied into the body of a brain wiped criminal, and was threatened with having his memories erased if he failed to perform adequately.

Comment: Was the closing line something like: "I don't need a heart transplant."  No, but I do."

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt You're thinking of 'Revival Meeting' by Dannie Plachta, to be found in '100 Great Science Fiction Short Short Stories', edited by Isaac Asimov and others

Comment: Thanks. That story is the closer, & your comment took me to other anthologies where I found it!! - “Cold sleep” by Sydney J. Bounds. Not exactly how I remembered  it, but this is it.

Comment: You would help the community here by posting the fact that you found it as an answer with the title and author and then accepting your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is “Cold sleep” by Sydney J. Bounds, found in [The 6th Fontana Book of Great Horror Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?296908) published in 1971.

Comment: Hi, this answer could be improved by adding quotes from the story that show how it matches OP's points

Comment: Incidentally, are the same person as wrote the initial question? If so, you can merge your accounts so that you can accept it.